# Reverse engineering a table with no primary key using Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to import an existing table in my Database using Doctrine's reverse engineering, but this table I'm importing doesn't have a primary key.
I know Doctrine doesn't allow to import tables without any primary keys, but I would like to know if there's a possibility to do it. I've been trying to edit Doctrine's code to allow it, but without any results for now.
Does anyone know a method? Or, if it's not possible, what are my options? I can't edit the database because it's not mine, so I need to manage this to import the table without "touching" the database.

Comment: Is this a table you will be importing often? It might be easier to get an export of the table and then manually add a primary key using code, then importing that into doctrine.

Comment: @mulquin it's not a table that needs to be imported often, just once. So your idea is correct and worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying a lot, I'd found a couple methods that can solve this. I will explain them to everyone who finds themselves in the same situations as me:

- **1st method**: The one [@mulquin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427345/mulquin) said. This method solves the problem by exporting the table and then adding, manually, a primary key using code. Once this is done, it can be imported using Doctrine.
- **2nd method**: Found by me. Creating the table using code directly and connecting it manually instead of using `make:entity`. You should create the two files, in Entity and Repository, and then write the code to make it match the table in the database, using `@ORM\Table`, `@ORM\Column`, etc. and writing everything just like Doctrine would generate it. You can take an existing entity generated by Doctrine to make sure you're not missing anything.